# Can I use startup.cs to load AppSettings

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

Can I write code in startup.cs...Configuration method to call my DataAccess layer and/or some other class to assign data to my static class after reading the configurations either from DB or from AppSettings from web.config file to read all my app configurations during the startup. I've tried to access my Static Class in startup.cs by adding reference to the library where my class resided, but I'm not able to access it in my asp.net MVC4 app.

```
 namespace CAS.Common
{
    public static class CommonConfiguration
    {
        public static string CDSRestClient { get; set; }
        public static string ClientIdValue { get; set; }
        public static string ClientSecretValue { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Code from Startup.cs

```
    using System.Configuration;
    using CAS.Common;

    namespace myWebApp
    {
        public partial class Startup
        {
            public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
            {
//This is the intended code, which I'm not able to do as I'm not able to access my static class here.
            CommonConfiguration.CDSRestClient = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["CDSRestClient"].ToString().Trim();
        CommonConfiguration.ClientIdValue = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["clientIdValue"].ToString().Trim();
        CommonConfiguration.ClientSecretValue = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["clientSecretValue"].ToString().Trim();
            }
        }
    }
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: Please check , if you can move that static file to app_code folder check , intellisense may fail but try after compiling. please let me know if that worked for you

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you have posted. Either your CAS library is not referenced from your MVC project as you mentioned, or the referenced library is targeting a higher .NET framework version than the MVC project.